# I have two text files which contains same data but in different columns and different rows

Tags: python

Example:
First file.txt:

```
a | b | c | d
0 | 1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6 | 7
```

Second file.txt

```
c | b | d | a
6 | 5 | 7 | 4
2 | 1 | 3 | 0
```

Suggest me some easy way to populate and compare the values.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't how StackOverflow works. Please try to write something yourself first.

Comment: the easiest way would be to bring both files structure into uniform columns order/format

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest saving them as `csv` files but text will work as well as long as you specify the correct separator.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('text1.csv', sep=',')
df2 = pd.read_csv('text2.csv', sep=',')
```

you can then sort the columns

```
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=1)
df2 = df2.sort_index(axis=1)
```

all the columns will now be in the same order.

you can aslo append the 2 DataFrames

```
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

The `pandas` has several methods for comparing `DataFrames`